# Rails route rewriting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flash, routes, flexpaper

I think this is an easy question.  I am using this useful Flash Document Reader called [FlexPaper](http://flexpaper.devaldi.com/index.php).  I have it embedded in one of my Show pages.  But when I click the a link on their tool bar to show the document in a new browser, it points to the following link:

> http://example.com/**intels**/FlexPaperViewer.swf?ZoomTime=0.5&FitPageOnLoad=false&PrintEnabled=false&SwfFile=%2FPaper.swf

which doesn't work, I get the following error:

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in IntelsController#show
>
> Couldn't find Intel with ID=FlexPaperViewer

but if I remove the "intels" from the path so the url looks like:

> http://example.com/FlexPaperViewer.swf?ZoomTime=0.5&FitPageOnLoad=false&PrintEnabled=false&SwfFile=%2FPaper.swf

It works fine.

My question is what is the best way to handle this? Can you write a route that rewrites a url that starts with `intels/FlexPaperViewer.swf` and remove the intels prefix? What would that look like?

Is there a better option?

Answer (score 0):

Juat a thought, how about placing the FlexPaperViewer.swf inside public/intels folder?

So the directory structure will be

```
<project-directory>/public/intels/FlexPaperViewer.swf
```

Doing this will make the link correct. It seems to be easier to do it this way.
Hopefully it helps.

**EDIT**

Another alternative will be to see how the link was generated, maybe there is a parameter that you can set when you embed the FlexPaper.

I am not aware of any route modification that can do what you want.  Maybe someone else can help on this.

Comment: Interesting thought, I will try that first thing this morning.

Comment: This doesn't work -- rails routing captures the url first and throws an error.  I updated the question with the error